# Insert into two different tables in one JDBC prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

This command:

```
INSERT INTO t1 values (d1)
INSERT INTO t2 values (d2)
```

I want to run in one prepared statement.  Logically they should be transactional so wrapped in a block.  Is this possible in JDBC which I understand doesn't allow multiple SQL operations per update?

Comment: You can't insert into two tables in one SQL statement. You can, however, do so in one *transaction*. (Edit: Apparently Oracle will allow this, see below)

Comment: Have you tried a multi-table insert using the `INSERT ALL` syntax?

Comment: If the inserts are logically coupled, then it can make sense to create a stored procedure which takes the input values as parameters and performs the multiple inserts. Then one jdbc call to the stored proc can be made.

Answer (score 1):

You need to begin a transaction, run both inserts, then commit. Or look into [allowMultiQueries=true](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) in your JDBC connection parameters.